# contentEditable и designMode

Tags: html

Чем отличаются атрибуты designmode и contenteditable? Вроде оба делают страницу редактируемой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы скопируйте кусок текста с разным форматированием и вставьте и туда и туда. Разница, как говорится, налицо!